# Express req.query becoming null

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have the following function which purpose will be to clean get parameters for a Restful api:

```
var clean_query = function(){
    return function(req, res, next){
         console.log(req.query)
         // Do stuff
         next();
    }
}
```

What is really is strange is when I try this function, here is what I see in the console:

```
✔ Express server listening on port 3000 in development mode
✔ MongoDB connection done.
✔ Server launched

{ param1: 'toto', param2: 'titi' }

/Users/... console.log(req.query)
                          ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of null
```

The error message is pretty clear : it tells me req is null.... But if you check console output, you can see that console.log(req.query) is outputing the content to the console so it is not empty in reality.

Do you know what can be my mistake?

EDIT : my route handling:

```
app.get(uri, clean_query(), get_list_func(schema));
```

EDIT 2 : My middlewares:

```
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(expressValidator());
app.use(express.cookieParser('secret'));
app.use(express.session( {
    store  : MongoStore( { db : 'dbtest' } ),
    key    : 'sessionid',
    cookie : { httpOnly : false },
    secret : 'secret'
}, function() {
    app.use(app.router);
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

EDIT 3 : strange if i remove next from function parameter, there is no more error but i can't use the function like that as i need to chain it with other controllers.

EDIT 4 : Wow, it seems that this function is called twice.... First time it is called req is ok, second time it is null. it must have something to do with next().

Comment: Can you show the code that handles the routing which invokes `clean_query`?

Comment: I edit my answer with this info.

Comment: Are you using any other custom middleware?

Comment: I added my middleware in edit.

Comment: is there a reason why you don't define clean_query as middleware instead of returning a middleware?

Comment: Can you show this function `get_list_func(schema)` ?

Comment: I found my issue : in the function get_list_func I had a call to a function with the same name as the other one so it was called twice. Thanks to your help issue is now solve.

Comment: Regarding the middleware thing : i tried to create a middleware based on this function, i added it to app.use() before app.use(app.router) but it didn't work as my app was not responding at all after it. I tested my different api with postman and saw that my server was stuck in processing the query :(

Comment: Why do you use `router` middleware as a session middleware callback?

Comment: Can you please just move the `app.use(router)` to the global context and use your `clean_query` function as a middleware right after the router?

Answer (score -2):

In the context where you define the function that will be returned there is no "req, res, next" defined. So it is expected that the req would be null.

You don't need to return a function in `clean_query`. You can just define `clean_query` as a middleware function as follows to resolve the issue.

```
var clean_query = function(req, res, next){
     console.log(req.query)
     // Do stuff
     next();
}
```

Comment: What do you think this line does: `return function(req, res, next){`

Comment: That line returns a middleware function instead of defining it. It is unnecessary here as `clean_query` is being used as a middleware. So why not define it as suggested.
You can use `app.get(uri, clean_query, get_list_func(schema));` instead of calling a function to get the middleware.

Comment: Do you agree that it's not related to the problem?

Comment: It might not be the root cause of the problem, but i think it is a way forward to diagnose as it helps to simplify.